# symfony2 form validation: form field name "not valid" error

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I created a Form in Symfony2, with the field "name" set to the type "text"... But for some reason, I can't use any spaces in this field... I get the following error:

```
form type name ("") is not valid
```

I tried renaming the field and changing the type to "textarea", but the problem remains.

Here is how the form is defined:

```
$builder -> add('name', 'text')
```

Can anybody tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

What about adding

```
public function getName()
{
    return 'your_type_name';
}
```

to your Type.

Note that the `getName()` method should return a unique identifier for the form "type".